# Using MPL3115A2 to get relative altitude of a drone

Tags: sensor, altimeter

I am using MPL3115A2 Altimeter to get the accurate relative altitude of my drone. I am getting an error of 30-60 cm without even moving the sensor. I have used several averaging and filtering methods but haven't got promising results.

Kindly help me by suggesting any improvements I can make with my current sensor. I am also open to suggestions involving other sensors which can give an error of at most +/-10 cm.

Comment: This 30-60 cm error, how long did that take to develop?

Comment: The error starts after 10 seconds and keeps occurring

Comment: The typical resolution of that sensor at sea level is 0.3 meter.  The slightes of measurement noise will give a change of 30 cm. If you need 10cm , you need a different sensor. Have a look at the BMP388. You'll have to do the conversion of pressure to altitude yourself though

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Aviation as defined in the Help Center, but belongs on Drones.se instead.

Comment: @RalphJ its fine I can delete it in a bit if it's bothering you and is inappropriate. I am new here and was just seeking help.

Comment: @DeltaLima Thank you so much for your help though! I will be experimenting with BMP388 and MS5611 to achieve better accuracy. Thanks again!